# C++ GtkWidget set default radio button in a group

Tags: radio-button, gtk

using GtkWidgets I have created radio buttons as follows:

```
GtkWidget *radio1, *radio2;

radio1 = gtk_radio_button_new (NULL);

radio2 = gtk_radio_button_new_from_widget (GTK_RADIO_BUTTON ( radio2 ));
```

When I launch the window radio1 is selected by default. Is there any way to change the default selection to radio2?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
gtk_toggle_button_set_active (GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON (radio2), TRUE);
```